# How to move folders and documents without 'Open with Explorer'

Tags: open-with-explorer

Our  company has installed Sharepoint 2013 but has not (yet) updated the Internet Explorer...and will not do so in the foreseeable future. With the old IE version, we are not able to transfer multiple folders and documents via the Explorer because the old IE version does not support a transfer. What can we do? Tons of folders and documents are currently being downloaded to our server and uploaded again to the right place in SP2013. Is there a user-friendly, easy way to do the transfer without the Explorer mode? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In site settings, there is an feature which allows you to manage the content and structure of your site.  In SharePoint 2010, it was accessible on the Site Actions menu but has been moved to Site Settings --> Site Actions --> Site Administration in SharePoint 2013.

See [Manage Content and Structure in SharePoint 2013.](https://wmostafaw.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/manage-content-and-structure-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions you can to map a network drive (or create a shortcut to a network location) to provide access to the content of a SharePoint library in Windows Explorer much like it is just another directory structure on a file server. [Link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-shortcut-to-map-network-drive) to how create a shortcut to (map) a network drive